# VB.NET & LiteDB Adding user in DB without duplicate

Tags: c#, vb.net, litedb

I am trying to Add Value of two textbox inside a Database.db with VB.NET and LiteDB without having a duplicate.

I have a Form with two textbox and a Button (button1 textbox1 and textbox2)
Textbox1.text = Nickname of the user
Textbox2.text = Email of the user
Button = When pressed it must add the value of the textbox to the local database.db but it must check if the value already exists, I don't want to have duplicate value. Like if the email value exists it show an error message.

Here is my code so far :

```
    Imports LiteDB
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using db = New LiteDatabase("data.db")
            'Check if email already exists  in the database
            'I don't want to have duplicate email, nickname
            'How can I do that?


            Dim Address = db.GetCollection(Of Addresses)("Address")
            Dim NewAddress = New Addresses With {
                .Nickname = TextBox1.Text,
                .Email = TextBox2.Text
            }
            Address.Insert(NewAddress)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
End Class
```

The source code of my projet can be downloaded here: https://easyupload.io/cnrh9s

Thanks everybody for taking your time to read me

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you consider a duplicate? For example, can you have multiple records with the same nickname but different emails?  Normally this achieved one of two ways.  1) Query the data before insert checking for uniqueness or 2) Using an Unique constraint/index which throws an exception on duplication.  On 2) I'm not sure LiteDB has that functionality, I've never got that far into it but the LiteDB docs should show you

Comment: A duplicate is a duplication of the same values (email only) one email address can have 1 nickname only.
LiteDB docs doesn't show VB.NET code, only c# and I am a pure newbies